# Creating custom sequential dataset in keras

Tags: keras, dataset

I have data saved in multiple csv files (16000+) and my aim is to create a dataset from these files. Each csv has the columns: "Source node", "Path", "Target node". In each of these columns is a one-hot encoded string, in "Source Node" and "Target node" the number of words in string is always 2, and in "Path" is always 27. Each csv file has 500 lines. I have found solutions online where I can create a dataset from one csv file, but not a solution where I can make a dataset from multiple csv files, where each each csv file is treated as a single sample of data. Has anyone done something similar or is it even possible?